# c# What is the diffrence TcpListener.Create(port) and new TcpListener(port) and why is one obsolete

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

There exists 2 diffrent Methods to instantiate TcpListner with only a port parameter.
One is calling `new TcpListener(port)` and the other `TcpListener.Create(port)`. The first one is marked obsolete (see the [microsoft refrencesource for the TcpListner class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPListener.cs,ad615384c4805213)) but the second one isn't.

The only diffrence seems to be that the latter sets `listener.Server.DualMode = true;` and then returns it.

I was wondering if it wouldn't have been easier to edit the original constructor `TcpListner(int port)` rather than having that static `Create(int port)`method left over.
Furthermore I was wondering what the design Idea behind such an implementation is. Why would one implement more or less the same way to instantiate an object and only mark one obsolete?

**If this question is to broad/big for stackoverflow, then please let me know in the comments where I can ask that question. I would then commence to close it here.**

Comment: Perhaps they forgot to mark the other one obsolete?

Comment: you're better off using the corefx source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/TCPListener.cs - reference source is wildly out of date

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that's what i thought initially aswell ^^,  
MarcGravell thanks for the link

Comment: I think they added the static method after making the constructor obsolete. When adding IPv6 support, they probably didn't want an IPv4-only constructor, but they also couldn't simply include IPv6 addresses as this would have an impact on existing applications. All guesses, though!

Comment: could be could be...

Comment: The Create() method was added in .NET 4.5, it uses IPAddress.IPv6Any instead.  Aggressively removing the IPv4 encumbered members was surely the goal.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the answer. Would you mind to formulate that as an answer to have a clear overview of information?

Comment: Maybe a Microsoft programmer shows up to turn "surely" into "definitely".  Well, could happen.  Just make sure that it does not matter when he doesn't, that should not be difficult.